# Open Source Android library to crop an image interactively

Tags: android, open-source, library, offline, image-editor

I would like my users to be able to interactively crop an image I have in memory (I can write it as a file if necessary).

Is there such a library, compatible with the GNU-GPLv3 Open Source license?

Requirements:

- Input: an image as memory object (file would be OK too as long as required format is common enough)
- Output: cropped image, preferably with a choice of PNG or JPG
- Interactive: Crop the image by moving cursors/rectangle or similar
- Works offline
- Java
- GNU-GPLv3-compatible

Non-requirements:

- Zoom feature not especially needed
- Quality loss is OK

Comment: Do you care what language? Is online via API okay? Also wondering about pricing? (Mainly just bumping but also I know an online option if that is of interest)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop is licensed under "the Apache License, Version 2.0" and can be used in java (see sample app)

Unfortunately parts are implemented in c++